# Continue or break did not work in ternary operator

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break, continue

I want to display multiples of 5  from 0 to 30 but not using normal logic. Tried with Ternary operator to display the result.

```
     int i=0;
     while(++i<=30)
     System.out.print(i%5==0?i:" ");
```

Output

```
      5    10    15    20    25
```

I don't want any spaces to be printed so instead on " "  in the above code I tried with continue statement to proceed with the loop but it did not worked.

```
 System.out.print(i%5==0?i:continue);
```

This code throws invalid expression. Why apart from expression special instructions did not work.  Please help me in giving expression that do nothing in the ternary operator.

Comment: did you try an empty string? `System.out.print(i%5==0?i:"");`

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate, since too many believe that the `ternary` operator is just another way of writing an `if-else` statement. That's not true and you shouldn't attempt to shoehorn it everywhere. Read the accepted answer for the duplicate to learn the full truth about the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `System.out.println()`. Since `System.out.println()` always expect something that can be print eg.- `String`, `int`, `byte` etc.

But here `continue` is a statement to manage the control flow of a program and in returns nothing.

In this context you don't need to add the `continue` statement, since the flow is automatically do what you expect. And since you want to avoid space then you can do this -

```
int i=0;
while(++i<=30)
   System.out.print(i%5==0?i : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator expects (in this case) an string, so to achieve your needs you must print an empty `String` if condition is false:

```
 System.out.print(i%5==0?i:"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an empty string

```
System.out.print(i%5==0?i:"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `System.out.print(continue)` is not valid. Check [java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) on how conditional operator works.

Ternary operator can be thought of as a conditional assignment. In your case, with `continue` you are not assigning anything (to the parameter of `System.out.print()`)

You can simply use `""` instead of `" "` and you would get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a keyword!  Even if this did work, you would still be passing it into `System.out.print` so would you expect a space/0-length string to be printed?

This is the equivalent:

```
System.out.print(i%5 == 0 ? "" + i : "");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need an argument to the println() method, not a directive.

But I think it's cleaner to use an "if" instead:

`if (i%5 == 0)
    System.out.println("" + i);`

Comment: Your example won't work. Ternary operator is not an alternative to if, as evidenced in this question for example.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right. Sorry. I'll edit my answer. (spoiled by C ;-)